# How do I edit the shortcuts behind the icons on the taskbar on Windows 11?

Tags: taskbar, administrator, shortcuts, windows-11

I want to make Windows Terminal always open as administrator.

How do I edit the shortcut behind the icon on the taskbar to check the "Run as administrator" option?

I tried creating a new shortcut to Windows Terminal on the desktop, and set it to "Run as administrator". This works fine, but then when I try to pin it to the taskbar after running it in an administrator context via the new shortcut, it looses it's settings and doesn't run as administrator.

Also, it doesn't let me drag the shortcut from the desktop to the taskbar.

Comment: I have found no way other than a desktop shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

In the following, "right-click" refers to the secondary button of your mouse. If you set your primary button to "right", you have to perform a left-click instead.

1. Right-click the desktop and select "New" > "Shortcut".
2. Enter "wt" (without the quotes) as location and click "Next".
3. Choose a name, e.g., "Windows Terminal (Admin)" and click "Finish".
4. Right-click the newly created shortcut and select "Properties".
5. (Optional) Download the [icon of Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/raw/main/res/terminal.ico), save it somewhere and choose it via "Change icon...".
6. Click "Advanced...", check "Run as administrator" and click "OK".
7. Save the shortcut by clicking "Apply" and "OK".
8. Right-click the shortcut on the desktop, then select "Show more options" and "Pin to taskbar".
9. (Optional) You can now delete the shortcut on the desktop. Doing so will not remove the shortcut on the taskbar.

The newly created shortcut on the taskbar will always launch Windows Terminal as admin.

Important: Make sure to select "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe" in step 2. "wt" should automatically expand to this target as soon as you hit "Next". Do not choose "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.14.2282.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe" because this path changes with every Terminal update. This is also why you have to download the icon manually.